# Any more concise way to construct parameter list for dynamic exec stored procedure?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm constructing a dynamic call to execute a stored procedure with 2 parameters.

Here's a snippet of how I'm putting parameters together prior to call...

Is there a more concise way to say this or any caveats?

```
    //parameters comes from: params SqlParameter[] parameters
    parameters.Select((x, i) => new
    {
        item = x,
        index = i
    })
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(obj =>
    {
        sb.AppendFormat($"@{paramNames[obj.index]}={obj.item.Value}, ");
    });

    var s = $"EXEC {storedProcName} {sb.ToString().TrimEnd(',',' ')}";

    return Context.Set<T>().FromSqlRaw(s).ToList();
}

return Context.Set<T>().FromSqlRaw($"EXEC {spName}").ToList();
```

Comment: Not sure the point of using EF for this, but you could avoid the list, one iteration through the parameters, the objects instantiations and the trimming if you just used `var joinedParams = string.Join(", ", parameters.Select((x, i) => $"@{paramNames[i]}={x.Value}"));`

Comment: You shouldn't paste the parameter values into the string.  It should just have the parameter names, then pas the `SqlParameter[]` as the second argument to `FromSqlRaw`

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft thank you, if you add this as an answer I'll mark it

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't paste the parameter values into the string. It should just have the parameter names, then pass the `SqlParameter[]` as the second argument to `FromSqlRaw`

eg

```
  foreach (var p in parameters)
  {
     sb.Append($"{p.Name}, ");
  }

  if (parameters.Count > 0)
  {
     sb.Length = sb.Length-2;
  }

  var sql = $"EXEC {storedProcName} {sb}";
  return Context.Set<T>().FromSqlRaw(sql, parameters).ToList();
```

Comment: If there are zero parameters, there isn't a trailing `, ` to trim.